# Android App Link Declare Website Association SHA-256 fingerprint Error

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-links

I am trying to Android App Linking via App Links Assistant in Android Studio (Android Studio version 3.3). I have entered all the site domain and Application ID correctly. I tried both signing config as well as Select keystore file option for production for creating the "Generate digital asset links file" still it is showing a dialog box saying:

Error
An error occurred while trying to get the SHA-256 fingerprint of the keystore file. Please make sure your keystore file is correct

[Error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hrQs.png)

Comment: this question already has answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345516/android-generate-digital-asset-link-keystore-file-for-signing-the-app