# Android, Generate Digital Asset Link: keystore file for signing the app

Tags: android, kotlin, keystore, android-keystore, digital-assets-links

I implemented universal linking for my Android app. Everything works fine so far. I click on a universal link and will be immediately redirected to the app. However, I have always used debug for the `Digital Asset Links`. For the release I need the signing config or the keystore file.

[image]

To sign my app I always use a created `xxxx.jks` file. If I specify this, an error occurs: `Error occured while trying to get the SHA-256 fingerprint` (See screenshot).

[image]

The error is very meaningless. That's why I'm a little confused. Do I use the right file? How do I get a better error description? I always use this file to sign my app for a new release. That doesn't cause any problems.

I already took the SHA-256 fingerprint from the App signature certificate from the Play Console. This doesn't really work properly. Whenever you click on my universal link, the app asks: `Should the link be opened with Chrome or with 'MyApp'?`

I am grateful for input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, the solution was simple. I just take the SHA256 from the google play console. This one you have to put in your assetlinks.json

Then I build a public beta and it works like expected.

[image]

Comment: you should add in your description, that you need to add the SHA256 into the assetlinks.json file

Comment: I suppose this should work for an internal beta as well? I.e. "internal test track".

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you can inform me if it works

Comment: there is issue tracker related this error here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200852825

Comment: It's now under configuration->app integrity

Comment: I have no assetlinks.json

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue and found out we don't need to use Android studios assets file generator anymore. It's available directly from the google play developer console as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when trying to set up an App Link, following the steps from https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.

For the '[Associate your app with your website](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing#associatesite)' steps I created a `signing config`, with keystore file using the command line `keytool`. But this didn't work, clicking `Generate Digital Asset Links file` gave "*An error occurred while trying to get the SHA-256 fingerprint of the keystore file. Please make sure your keystore file is correct.*". I doublechecked my keystore file and tried again, but the issue remained.

The fix is to use Android Studio's `New Key Store` wizard and use that keystore file instead.
You can open the wizard via Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK... > APK > Next > below the 'Key store path' option click 'Create new ...'. See also https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key.

Answer (score 0):

You need generate Digital Asset Links with debuge signing config and replace SHA like in answer @kuzdu